# Changing Haskell's Functor for Metaprogramming

Tags: haskell, metaprogramming, dsl

My knowledge of category theory isn’t very good. So please bear with me.

I’ve been reading [Monads Made Difficult](http://www.stephendiehl.com/posts/monads.html)

and saw the following definition.

```
class (Category c, Category d) => Functor c d t where
  fmap :: c a b -> d (t a) (t b)
```

from that site I read that the Functor type in Haskell’s prelude is really an Endofunctor. (where both category c and d in the above class are Hask)

After reading through the page, I was wondering. Would Haskell be better suited for meta-programming if it used real Functors and not just Endofunctors?

say we have the following (the Js stands for Javascript)

```
data Js a where
  litInt :: Integer -> Js Integer
  litString :: String -> Js String
  var :: String -> Js a
  lam :: String -> Js b -> Js (a -> b)
  let :: String -> Js a -> Js b -> Js b
  ap :: JsFunc a b -> Js a -> Js b

type JsFunc a b = Js (a -> b)
```

now back to the definition of Functor above

```
class (Category c, Category d) => Functor c d t where
  fmap :: c a b -> d (t a) (t b)
```

we can have c be JsFunc, d be Hask and have t be Js

this will give us a Functor for Js. That I could not do using Haskell’s Endofunctor.

I could not find anything for the Apply or Applicative type-classes defined in the same way as this Functor. Could the same be done with those too?

And correct me if I’m wrong. But the same can not be done for Monad, because it really an instance of an Endofunctor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first –

> ... if it used real Functors and not just Endofunctors ...

Haskell functors *are* real functors. Only, the `Functor` class doesn't allow *any* kind of general functors, but only the specific ones that are endofunctors on **Hask**.

Indeed, non-endo–functors are interesting; mathematicians use them all the time. And while as you say, there can't be non-endofunctor monads, an analogue to `Applicative` *is* possible: that class is really just a nice Haskell interface for [monoidal functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_functor), which can be defined between different categories. Looks about like this:

```
class (Functor r t f, Category r, Category t) => Monoidal r t f where
  pureUnit :: () `t` f ()
  fzipWith :: (a, b) `r` c -> (f a, f b) `t` f c
```

To actually use this anywhere as conveniently as the standard `Applicative` class though, you'll need a bit more than just the `Monoidal` class. This has been tryied in a [couple](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/category-extras) of [libraries](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-category). I also [wrote one](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative-Constrained.html). But, well... it doesn't exactly look beautiful...

```
class (Functor f r t, Cartesian r, Cartesian t) => Monoidal f r t where
  pureUnit :: UnitObject t `t` f (UnitObject r)
  fzipWith :: (ObjectPair r a b, Object r c, ObjectPair t (f a) (f b), Object t (f c))
              => r (a, b) c -> t (f a, f b) (f c)

class (Monoidal f r t, Curry r, Curry t) => Applicative f r t where
  -- ^ Note that this tends to make little sense for non-endofunctors. 
  --   Consider using 'constPure' instead.
  pure :: (Object r a, Object t (f a)) => a `t` f a 

  (<*>) :: ( ObjectMorphism r a b
           , ObjectMorphism t (f a) (f b), Object t (t (f a) (f b))
           , ObjectPair r (r a b) a, ObjectPair t (f (r a b)) (f a)
           , Object r a, Object r b )
       => f (r a b) `t` t (f a) (f b)
  (<*>) = curry (fzipWith $ uncurry id)
```

I don't know if any of these frameworks would allow you to write the applicative JS code you want in a practical way. Possibly, but actually I rather suspect it would get *very* messy. Also note that, while you now have applicatives floating around, this doesn't mean you can actually do what's normally done with **Hask** applicatives in Js code – on the contrary, you'd actually need to wrap those applicatives as transformers around the `Js` type.

You might want to consider abandoning “JS values” as such completely, and *only* write in a category/arrow paradigm instead. I.e., turn the definition around:

```
data JsFunc a b where
    litInt :: Integer -> JsFunc () Integer
    litString :: String -> JsFunc () String
    var :: String -> JsFunc () a
    lam :: String -> JsFunc () b -> JsFunc a b
    let :: String -> JsFunc () a -> JsFunc () b -> JsFunc () b
    ap :: JsFunc a b -> JsFunc () a -> JsFunc () b

type Js = JsFunc ()
```

here, we use `()` as the [terminal object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_and_terminal_objects) of the `JsFunc` category – which makes the `Js a ≡ JsFunc () a` arrows equivalent to what we normally call *values* (at least if we don't consider strictness semantics). If you go that route, pretty much everything needs to be written point-free, but there's [syntax to pretend otherwise](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.2/docs/html/users_guide/arrow-notation.html), and you can nicely incorporate functors and even monads (as Kleisli arrows).

Comment: shouldn't that be `lam :: String -> JsFunc () b -> JsFunc a b`?

Comment: Would haskell's Arrow type class have to change to use arrow do-notation? The 'arr' would lift arbitrary haskell functions into JsFunc that can not get translated to JavaScript.

Comment: @clinux: right, I'd forgotten about that. It's actually a bit of a hack in the `Arrow` class to allow lifting arbitrary Haskell functions – the class is IMO _supposed_ to represent well-pointed monoidal categories, but these require a whole lot of methods (`fst`, `const` etc.), which can be seven-in-a-swipe'd with `arr`. That's also something I have different [in my categories library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow-Constrained.html).

Comment: Yeah, thats right. You can do without 'arr' with a fist full of extra methods. Have you seen GArrow? http://www.megacz.com/berkeley/garrows/ . I was thinking, if you can generalise an arrow in this way, can you also generalise an applicative? Every arrow that has its first type held fixed (not the correct terminology) is an instance of an Applicative. Does there exist a GApplicative?

Comment: Actually your definition of Applicative is like the generalised applicative I'm looking for? It just confuses me to read it :p

Comment: @clinux: `Applicative` is actually _equivalent_ to `Monoidal` – but `pure` only works for endofunctors, and `(<*>)` only in cartesian closed categories. So,...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75124/discussion-between-clinux-and-leftaroundabout).

Answer (score 3):

According to [this mailing list post](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell/2004-July/014315.html), applicative functors are known in the math literature as "weakly symmetric lax monoidal functors". A (brief, not careful) look at the nlab page for [lax monoidal](http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/monoidal+functor) suggests that this concept is also parameterized by two categories, so you can probably extend this parametric functor class to a parametric applicative class with some work.

As you say, monads are endofunctors, so they can't be parameterized by two categories. But the one category they have as a parameter need not be Hask; so one could give a parameterized monad as well, like

```
class Functor c c f => Monad c f where
    return :: c a (f a)
    join :: c (f (f a)) (f a)
```

Then we can use a sort of standard trick to define bind:

```
(=<<) :: Monad c m => c a (m b) -> c (m a) (m b)
(=<<) f = join . fmap f
```

The `(.)` operation here is the composition from the `Category` class, not function composition from `Prelude`.

Comment: So that means I could have 'c' be JsFunc, and say I had a javascript prelude which had a Maybe type ('f' becomes Maybe). It would allow me to make a monad instance of the javascript Maybe type for the code generator? I'd have to use Js's 'lam' instead of haskell's lambda, but still pretty cool.

Answer (score 2):

> we can have c be JsFunc, d be Hask and have t be Js

Well, no we can't exactly since `JsFunc` is an unsaturated type synonym, so we can't instantiate a variable (`c`) to it.

You could create a newtype

```
newtype JsCat a b = JsCat (Js (a -> b))
```

and then create a `Functor JsCat (->) Js` like you say.

However, this doesn't give you anything new since if we expand what you wanted the type of `fmap` to be, it becomes

```
fmap :: JsFunc a b -> (->) (Js a) (Js b) -- or
fmap :: Js (a -> b) -> Js a -> Js b
```

which is none other than an `Apply` instance for `Js`. So, I'm not sure why you want to make this into a functor when it already fits into an existing abstraction.

Comment: The Apply type-class is a subclass of Functor (Haskell's Endofunctor), so you really can not make it an instance of Apply.